# Behavior of aggregate functions in the RANK() window function (SQL)

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

When I use the 'PARTITION BY' clause of the Rank() window function, I am only receiving one row in the result table when I believe there should be one row per partition.

Example:

```
Input project table
+-------------+-------------+
| project_id  | employee_id |
+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | 1           |
| 1           | 2           |
| 1           | 3           |
| 2           | 1           |
| 2           | 4           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

This query attempts to rank the project_id on the number of associated employees

```
SELECT project_id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY COUNT(employee_id)) AS number_of_contributors FROM project
```

```
Output
| project_id | rank_by_headcount |
| ---------- | ----------------- |
| 1          | 1                 |
```

I expected to receive something like

```
| project_id | rank_by_headcount |
| ---------- | ----------------- |
| 1          | 1                 |
| 2          | 2                 |
```

How come there is only one result row?

It works when I `group by project_id`, however it seems like I shouldn't need to.

```
SELECT project_id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(employee_id) DESC) AS rank_by_headcount FROM project
```

GROUP BY project_id

```
Output
| project_id | rank_by_headcount |
| ---------- | ----------------- |
| 1          | 1                 |
| 2          | 2                 |
```

As an aside -- I have even tried removing the 'PARTITION BY' clause, but it yields the same result:

```
SELECT project_id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(employee_id) DESC) AS rank_by_headcount FROM project
```

```
Output
| project_id | number_of_contributors |
| ---------- | ---------------------- |
| 1          | 1                      |
```

Comment: You use aggregate function COUNT without GROUP BY clause. In this case the whole rowset is treated as one group. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - and you will see according error message.

Comment: The published code errors https://dbfiddle.uk/8WOfZGaz

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow :

```
SELECT project_id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(employee_id) DESC) AS number_of_contributors 
FROM project
GROUP BY project_id
```

It can also be done in two steps: first, calculate the number of employees per project id, and then apply `RANK()` on this dataset:

```
SELECT project_id, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY count_employee DESC) AS number_of_contributors
FROM (
  SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) AS count_employee 
  FROM project
  GROUP BY project_id
) AS s
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1kUzkrw-)